# Cann't Connect to WPA2 Enterprise PEAP Connection

Tags: network-manager, internet

If any one can please tell me how to connect WPA2 Enterprise PEAP connection.
Please I have installed, Ubuntu, Linux Mint etc so many other linux distros but my internet is not connected and always asked for password again and again.

Also I have seen some post where they tell to remove system ca certs = false but there is no such line in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder.

So please tell me step by step how to connect my internet
Thanks

Comment: You tried to restart the network-manager

Comment: Please add that link!